# How can I go deep by a variable amount into a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a multidimensional array called `$organized_comments` and an array called `$ancestors` which is given by a function (unimportant) which lists all ancestors of an element in `$organized_comments`.

`$organized_comments` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [child] => Array
                       (
                           [id] => 2
                           [child] => Array
                                   (
                                   [id] => 3
                                   [child] => Array
                                           (
                                           )
                                   )
                       )
        )
)
```

And I ran my function with the input as `3` and its output was `$ancestors` equal to `[1,2]` which means that `3` ancestors from farthest out to closest were `1` and then `2`.

I want to make a function that runs through `$ancestors` in a way that when it reaches `[id] => 3`, I can insert a value into the `[child]` key.

What I tried was this:

```
$ancestors_count = count($ancestors);
    $i = 0;
    $thing = '$organized_comments';
    foreach($ancestors as $parent_id_here) {
        $i = $i + 1;
        if ($i != $ancestors_count) {
        $thing = $thing . "['$parent_id_here']";
        } else {
        ///MY ACTION
        }
    }
```

But that obviously didn't work since I was just adding strings.  What can I do to get to `[id] => 3`?

Thank you!  Please tell me if I have been unclear at any point.

Comment: Research recursion

Comment: Actually, what you are looking for might be more along the lines of materialized path

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `$thing` concatenation logic, I conclude that `['child']` can only contain a single element, and array keys always match corresponding item id.

```php
echo 'Before: ', json_encode($organized_comments, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "\n"; // more readable than print_r()

$ancestors = [1, 2];
$item = &$organized_comments;
foreach ( $ancestors as $ancestor_id ) {
    $item = &$item[$ancestor_id]['child'];
}
if ( $item ) {
    // $id = array_key_first($item); // php 7.3+
    $id   = array_keys($item)[0];
    $item = &$item[$id];
    // do your thing here
    $item['foo'] = 'bar';
}
unset($item); // destroy reference to avoid accidental data corruption later

echo 'After: ', json_encode($organized_comments, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "\n";
```

Output:

```
Before: {
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "child": {
            "2": {
                "id": 2,
                "child": {
                    "3": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "child": []
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
After: {
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "child": {
            "2": {
                "id": 2,
                "child": {
                    "3": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "child": [],
                        "foo": "bar"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```